# What is the best way or alternative for indexing an encrypted column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, index, encryption

So in Oracle, one can use function indexes.  MySQL unfortunately, does not have function indexes (as far as I know).  Can someone share how they were successfully able to optimize a query that requires encryption on the very column that needs to be indexed in order to optimize the query?

For example, say I have the following query:

```
select some_thing from classified_table
where user_name = AES_ENCRYPT(user_name, v_EncryptKey)
```

If the user_name column is the only appropriate column for indexing, is there a way to create an index on the classified_table for user_name? Assume classified_table contains all mentioned columns.

Comment: *MySQL unfortunately, does not have function indexes (as far as I know).* Version-dependent. 8.0.13+ can - [Functional Key Parts](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-functional-key-parts)

Comment: Thanks very much for the response.  I won't be using version 8.0 for some time (company not there yet).  Any suggestions if using v5.7 is my only option?

Comment: For 5.7 - only [CREATE TABLE and Generated Columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html)

Comment: Is a user_name_hash as a generated column hashing the username, [with an index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-secondary-indexes.html), and then appending `AND user_name_hash = 'xxx'` to your query a reasonable trade-off?